# What is meant by a generator of $H^1(I,\partial I; R)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $I$ be the closed interval $[0, 1]$.

On pg. 211 of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, the author writes:

> "... $\delta(1_0)$ is a generaotr of $H^1(I, \partial I, R)$ ... any other generator $\alpha$ is a scalar multiple of $\delta(1_0)$ by a unit in $R$ ..."

My confusion is because of the following. Note that $H^1(I, \partial I; R)\cong H^1(S^1; R)$ since $(I, \partial I)$ is a good pair.
Now since first cohomology is the hom of fisrt homology, we have

$$H^1(S^1; R)\cong \text{hom}(H_1(S^1), R)$$
Here $\text{hom}$ denotes the set of all the (abelian) group homomorphisms.
So in $\text{hom}(H_1(S^1), R)$, the multiplicative structure on $R$ is not important.

Since $H_1(S^1)=\mathbf Z$, we have $H^1(S^1; R)\cong \text{hom}(\mathbf Z, R)$, which as a group is isomorphic to $(R, +)$. So this may not be cyclic.

Therefore I am not able to understand what Hatcher means when he says something is a generator of $H^1(I, \partial I; R)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means a generator as an $R$-module.  $H^1(I,\partial I;R)\cong R$ is cyclic as an $R$-module, even if it isn't as an abelian group.